# Can a draft drawn on a US bank be used overseas?

Tags: check, international

Can a draft drawn on a US bank be used overseas?

If the answer is different for personal checks versus bank checks, then answer for both cases.

Basically what I want to know is if a person in a foreign country can deposit my check in their account successfully or not.

Comment: I've successfully deposited cheques from the U.S. into my Canadian bank account. Funds were held for 30 days to ensure clearing, and the bank charged a foreign exchange fee. We aren't exactly "overseas" though.

Comment: This depends on the other country involved and the banks in question. two decades ago, it was routine, one could encash personal check or bankers check outside as other means were not available or expensive. Today with quite a few alternatives, volume of international checks going down and fraud increasing, there are less number of banks who would undertake this pain. Most Banks would have stopped such services as these are no longer beneficial